# how to delay a method

Tags: java, netbeans

I,m doing a othello game and I have done an Ai which is a easy code. But when I run my code the Ai runs just right after i have clicked, I want some delay on it, I don't really know how to do, as I said, it runs to fast and I want the Ai to run like after 2 seconds.

```
board.artificialIntelligence();
```

My method Ai is stored in board class, and I want it in my panel class, btw I'm using NetBeans.

Answer (score 5):

if you do `Thread.sleep(TIME_IN_MILLIS)` your game will become unresponsive for 2 seconds (unless this code is running in another thread).

The best approach I can see is having a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) in your class and submit the AI task to it. Something like:

```
public class AI {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService execService;

    public AI() {
        this.execService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    public void startBackgroundIntelligence() {
        this.execService.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // YOUR AI CODE
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Swing, you can use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to invoke the method after a predefined delay

```
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         board.artificialIntelligence();
      }
   });
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture = 2000;
    Date timeToRun = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                     board.artificialIntelligence();
        }
    }, timeToRun);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.sleep(2000)` to wait for two seconds

Answer (score 0):

> Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a
>   specified period.

In your case:

```
Thread.sleep(2000); // will wait for 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your code call

```
try {    
    Thread.sleep(2000);

} catch(InterruptedException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for 2 seconds using this code:

```
long t0,t1;
t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
do{
   t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
}while (t1-t0<2000);
```

Comment: Never do this. It'll burn CPU cycles for absolutely no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the main thread to block, start a new thread which waits 2 seconds then makes the call (then dies), like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } (catch InterruptedException e) {}
        board.artificialIntelligence();
    }
}).start();
```